# En "hoy es un día lluvioso", ¿cuál es el sujeto?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, sujeto

Buscando si hoy es el sujeto en español de la frase hoy es un día lluvioso,  me encontré con esta respuesta que no sé si es correcta:

> [¿un adverbio puede cumplir la funcion de sujeto?](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110119061301AACw1Hj)
>
> El adverbio cumple la función de circunstancial siempre. Para que sea
> núcleo del sujeto se debe sustantivar
>
> Ejemplo: *Juan vino ayer*
>
> "Ayer" es adverbio de tiempo y funciona como circunstancial de tiempo.  Si
> Digo "El ayer me interesa"  Ese *ayer* acompañado de artículo "el" se
> sustantiva y en ese caso es sujeto.
>
> Fuente(s): docente de Lengua

Entonces, si entiendo bien, ¿"hoy" no sería el sujeto en la oración de mi pregunta? ¿Cuál sería?

Comment: @mdewey that I've seen an answer to a question saying that sentence is wrong in an english forum

Comment: sorry, sort of, here it is https://www.italki.com/question/168050

Comment: @mdewey my bad, it is sintactically right then to say "today is a rainy day" or it's common but wrong?

Comment: @mdewey , ok, thanks, I edited the questions. The moderators can move out the comments to the chat I believe

Comment: I have deleted my comment, perhaps best if you do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copiado de la *[Nueva Gramática Española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMVFbdkWTxpjZApX)*:

> El problema que se analiza puede concebirse como indicio de que la noción de 'sujeto' contiene varios rasgos [...], de forma que ciertas oraciones satisfacen tan solo algunos de ellos. No parece, en efecto, que pueda ponerse en duda que *hoy* es sujeto en *Hoy será recordado como el día en que Costa Rica fijó su posición en el referendo del TLC* (*Nación* [C. Rica] 7/10/2007), lo que se debe, en buena medida, a que la estructura sintáctica de dicha oración permite destacar el adverbio demostrativo como el elemento del que se predica cierta información.

Este texto deja claro que en la frase "hoy es un día lluvioso", *hoy* es el sujeto del cual se predica algo (que es un día lluvioso). Otros adverbios que pueden ser sujetos de la oración son *ayer* y *mañana*. También es cierto que, en los registros formales más cuidados, se tiene a evitar este tipo de construcciones y sustituirlas por "el día de hoy es [un día] lluvioso", en la que el sujeto sería "el día de hoy".

En todo caso, no se puede considerar *hoy* como un sustantivo aunque haga de sujeto, sino que sigue siendo un adverbio demostrativo. La gramática también explica que:

> Se ha observado en muchas ocasiones que los adverbios de tiempo y de lugar ocupan a menudo el espacio que corresponde a los sujetos nulos o expletivos en ciertas oraciones impersonales (como ∅ en *∅ hizo mucho frío*).

Si se dice "hizo mucho frío", la oración es impersonal claramente. Pero si se dice "ayer hizo mucho frío", aunque sigue siendo impersonal ya al delimitar el espacio de tiempo puede hacer que *ayer* se considere como el elemento que llena el hueco dejado por ∅ (el sujeto nulo).

Comment: sigue siendo un adverbio hoy en esa frase, o se comporta como un sustantivo?

Comment: @Pablo completo mi respuesta con esta nueva duda.

Comment: ¿El único argumento para decir que _hoy_ no está sustantivado es la falta de artículo? Lo pregunto sinceramente, porque aunque tiene sentido, me choca un poco. Creo que la fuente, más que descartar la sustantivación, la elude (sugiriendo que es poco probable). El mismo argumento de que _hoy_ no alterna libremente con _el día de hoy_ (33.2c), sirve para decir que _día_ no es sujeto omitido. Esto y los demás argumentos serían compatibles con decir que _hoy_ es sustantivable sólo en algunos contextos.